# How to deploy grails war file on cpanel (support tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, grails, deployment, war, cpanel

I have a web application with grails, I want to deploy this web application in cPanel by using .war file.I follow this [guid](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Deploy+Java+Applications),
first I created database then added database info on my app datasource, made war file and uploaded war on PUBLIC_HTML file on cPanel, renamed war file to zip file and extract it. I checked url(sampleDomain.com/myApp) but it shows error like below:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /myApp was not found on this server.
```

I don't have any idea how to deploy this war file.

Comment: Are you using, linux or windows server, incase of linux server custom bash script would be the way to go you can also check out tool called jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Given that your tomcat is working on your cPanel, you would save your war file in "webapps" folder and then start tomcat. Its tomcat's job to unzip the file and serve it. You don't need to manually unzip the war file.